# Limit Social Sharing Options and Set Custom Message for Each Service

Tags: objective-c, ios, share, social-networking

I am about to implement a share button calling the default modal sharing activities view.

Here's what I got so far.

```
NSString *textToShare = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Looking forward to meet you at %@",[eventItemObject eventName]];;
NSURL *url = [eventItemObject eventWebsiteURL];
NSArray *activityItems = [[NSArray alloc]  initWithObjects:textToShare,url,nil];

UIActivity *activity = [[UIActivity alloc] init];
NSArray *applicationActivities = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:activity, nil];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:applicationActivities];

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This is called when I press the sharing button.

Challenge:

1. Limit the sharing option to e.g. Facebook, Twitter, Mail (It now also shows Copy to Clipboard and Weibo)
2. Assign custom sharing messages/strings for each sharing method. (now the *textToShare* string is used for all services)

After some research I think this can be done with the new SLComposeViewController (in iOS6), but I am not sure where/how to call it correctly. Any practical advice or example is appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

You can specify which activities not to show be using the activityViewController's `setExcludedActivityTypes:`. Example:

```
[activityVC setExcludedActivityTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                     UIActivityTypeMessage,UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                                     UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                                     UIActivityTypePrint,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                                     nil]];
```

As far as sending specific content to different activities goes, I've spent the last day or so trying to figure out how to do that. I'll update this post to include this info if/when I figure it out.